# Spring AOP Point cut validate Annotation Present

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am writing one simple `afterReturning` annotation `point-cut`. But I would like to execute the `aop` if and only if method arguments pass certain criteria

```
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.test.create(*))", returning = "entity")
public void createAdvice(final AbstractEntity entity) {
    if (entity.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
        //do something
    }
}

@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.test.create(*))", returning = "entityList")
public void createListAdvice(final List<AbstractEntity> entityList) {
    BaseEntity entity = entityList.get(0);
    if (entity.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
        //do something
    }
}


@MyAnnoation
public class Entity{
     String a;
     String b;
}
```

But the point is only few of my entity classes will have custom Annotation `MyAnnotation`.
I want to pull this control logic to `point-cut` instead of validating inside method.

Any idea how can I do that validation?

Another question is, `AfterReturning` aop method can return value. What happens to that value which is returned by the method?

```
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.test.create(*))", returning = "entity")
public Object createAdvice(final AbstractEntity entity) {
    if (entity.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
        //do something
    }
    return something; //what will happen to this object. how it will be handled
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@within` [pointcut designator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

> **@within** - limits matching to join points within types that have the
>   given annotation (the execution of methods declared in types with the
>   given annotation when using Spring AOP)

For example

```
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.test.create(*)) && @within(com.example.MyAnnotation)", returning = "entity")
```

Concerning your second question, the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-after-returning) states

> Please note that it is not possible to return a totally different
>   reference when using after-returning advice.

So, although the code allows you to declare your method as having a return type other than `void`, the implementation of `AfterReturning` ignores it. You can see this behavior in Spring's AOP implementation of `AspectJAfterReturningAdvice#afterReturning(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the documentation. How the `within` works if the returning value is `List<E>` type?

Comment: @Reddy The returning value (or its type) doesn't matter. `@within` applies to the advised method's enclosing type. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: if you look at my updated post, presently my validation code looks something like this which is not so good. and I guess `within` purpose is different from what I am looking at

Comment: @Reddy Ah, no. That requirement is way too custom to be supported by the built-in pointcut designators. You'll have to write that in the advice method.

Comment: thanks :) I was just thinking any other delegated way to get things done.